# Selenium grid import root ca certificate

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, selenium

I use selenium grid/zalenium. I need to import root ca certificate into the chrome inside grid, how can I import it from robot framework desired capabilities? I can't just ignore certificate, I need to import it and trust it.